# What dictates the Higgs potential of the Standard model?

Tags: supersymmetry, higgs, cosmological-inflation, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

As far as I know, there is no convincing answer for why does the Higgs potential has a 'Mexican hat' shape. Apart from Lorentz invariance and gauge invariance, the Higgs potential of the Standard model has been chosen somewhat arbitrarily.

*Do more advanced theories that go beyond the Standard model such as Grand Unified theories, supersymmetry or the theory of inflation have any deeper answer?*

Comment: See [this PSE answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/395457/84967) (last paragraph).

Answer (score 2):

Working in natural units ($c=\hbar=1$), each physical quantity has a mass dimension. For the action $S=\int d^4 x \mathcal{L}$ in 4-dimensional spacetime, it's $0$; for $x^\mu$, it's $-1$; for $d^4 x$, it's $-4$; for $\mathcal{L}$, it's 4. A kinetic term $\partial_\mu\phi^\ast\partial^\mu\phi$ in this Lagrangian density implies $\partial_\mu\phi$ is of dimension $2$ while $\partial_\mu$ is of dimension $1$, so $\phi$ is of dimension $1$. Thus if $\lambda_n\phi^n$ is in the potential $\lambda_n$ has mass dimension $4-n$. Renormalisation typically requires this to be $\ge 0$, so we stop at $\phi^4$; this is called scalar $\phi^4$ theory.

Well, technically if we want a $U(1)$ theory for the Higgs, we're limited to $(\phi^\ast\phi)^k$ terms with $k\in\{0,\,1,\,2\}$. As long as neither of the $k>0$ terms has coefficient $\neq 0$, we're done. We can shift the $k=0$ term by an arbitrary constant, so feel free to set it to $0$ or make the potential a perfect-square function of $\phi^\ast\phi$.

You may wish to work out what happens in $d$-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: Is it essential to impose renormalizability? @J.G.

Comment: @SRS A predictive theory needs a finite number of parameters, so it has to cut the potential at some finite power of $\phi$. Luckily, renormalizability provides a natural placement for this cap.  If you want to learn more about it, look up relevant, marginal & irrelevant couplings.

Comment: @J.G. That's not entirely true: you can have a predictive theory with an infinite number of parameters, as long as only a finite number of them are relevant. Moreover, you don't need to cut the potential at some finite power of $\phi$ to have a finite number of parameters: for example, the sine-Gordon model has a single parameter, and a potential with an infinite number of terms.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That's true, although "my Higgs has a sine-Gordon potential" is a bit of a "because I say so" hypothesis. Ideally we want to say, "I don't know what the power series looks like, but I do know which coefficients are allowed to be relevant, so I'll truncate there."

Comment: @J.G. So are you saying there is no scope of changing the Higgs potential within Standard model if it is assumed to be renormalizable?